# Adding JavaScript variable to href value in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript I'm trying to edit. Basically the JavaScript is creating a button to click on if the color is red, which works, but I need to add the date to the actual href value.

```
if (color == "#DC3545") {
  var date = $("#selected_date").val();

  $("div.toolbar")
    .html('<a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit.php?Date=+date" >Edit Day</a>');
}
```

Comment: Look at the colorization in the question.  It is using a literal string.

Comment: Yes, code highlighting can provide valuable clues. If your variable appears the same color as your string something's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix up your string concatenation:

```
$("div.toolbar")
  .html('<a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit.php?Date=' + date + '" >Edit Day</a>');
  // ---------------------------------------------------^----------^
```